# Inputting 2D array in to conv2D layer

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm building a DQN that takes a 24x10 array of 0,1,2 (representing a tetris board) and a int 0-5 (representing the current playable tetramino)

I flatten my array and convert it to a Tensor before inputting it to my convolutional layers but this is the error I keep on getting

```
Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [16, 3, 240, 240], but got 1-dimensional input of size [240] instead
```

I've tried reducing the Kernel size and stride as well as not flattening the array but neither has worked.

For reference this is my DQN

```
class DQN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        

        self.conv1_board = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=240, stride=1) #3 input channels for 0,1,2 . kernel_size 240 for length of tensor
        self.conv2_board = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=240, stride=1)
        self.conv3_board = nn.Conv2d(32, 6, kernel_size=240, stride=1)

        self.conv1_piece = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=240, stride=1) #in channels 6 as 6 possible values 
        self.conv2_piece = nn.Conv2d(16, 6, kernel_size=240, stride=1)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 32)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32, 6)
        

        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()

    def flt_totns(self, arr):
        flt = []
        for l in arr:
            flt.extend(l)
        return torch.FloatTensor(flt)

    def forward(self, states): #inputs to conv layers should be Tensors not list. convert list => tensor 
        board, piece = states
        board = self.flt_totns(board)
        embed_board = flatten(self.conv3_board(self.conv2_board(self.conv1_board(board))))
        embed_piece = flatten(self.conv2_piece(self.conv1_piece(piece)))
        embed_joined = torch.cat([embed_board, embed_piece])

        return self.fc2(self.fc1(embed_joined))
```

I'm very new to CNNs in pytorch so I'm sure a lot of my reasoning is faulty. For example I'm still not sure how Kernel size exactly relates to the shape of your input, or if input channels still applies to array inputs. Buy any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your images are of shape `24 x 10 x 3` then your convolutions should receive a tensor of shape  `None x 24 x 10 x 3`, where `None` corresponds to the batch dimension.
Also, your kernel size should be much smaller. Try something in the range of 3-8. The larger your kernel-size, the less general your model is. The reasoning here is that your `240 x 240` kernel can detect patterns of that exact size. However, there are way less possible pixel combinations in a `3 x 3` window than there are in a `240 x 240` window. Thats why the most common kernel size is `3 x 3`.

Comment: Also a kernel-size of 240 is larger than your image, so the operation should not be possible with this big a kernel.